# Unable to get Requirements coverage information from QC 12 via REST api?

Tags: rest, hp-quality-center

Unable to get Requirements coverage information from QC 12 via REST api?

I am using QC 12 in my project. Can anyone tell me is it possible to get test coverage information from requirements via QC 12 using REST api?

Answer (score 0):

Rest api is preview version and not fully available as OTAClient api. Many functions are not available. Few enhancements are made in 11.5 and 12.0/2 but still it lacks many of the function. Better you use OTAClient which is full fledged api to communicate with HP.

Only requirement traceability links are added in rest version of 12.0/2

Answer (score 0):

there is a possible workaround for that. First point should be the usage of a QC version higher than 11.

Having said that, it is possible to use a call to "requirement-coverages" and check for the required "required-id", for instance:
1)
    GET https://SERVER/qcbin/rest/domains/DOMAIN/projects/PROJECT/requirement-coverages?query={requirement-id[10];}

This will give you back an xml file (in case requirement exist) with a list of "test-ids" linked to that requirement. 
Already at this point you have the knowledge of "test-coverage"--> each test cases will have his own "pass or fail".

2) If you are looking for a specific test-id, then you can check if in those test-ids is available the test-id you are looking for.

Hopefully the command above solve your query. I know that this is quite late reply, but hope to help somebody else! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this api. You will get all the requirement to requirement mappings.

http://SERVER/qcbin/rest/domains/DOMAIN/projects/PROJECT/req-traces?login-form-required=y
Also if you need a list of all the api's exposed in REST, use the below link:
http://SERVER/qcbin/rest/resource-list .